# QueryTables Error: Expected ')'

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

Getting an error: "Expected ')'" on Line 22, Char 60 (i.e. right at the "connection" in the QueryTables.Add function). This VBA is being called by a batch file. I'm trying to understand what is wrong with my syntax so that I can invoke the VB job to turn a text file into a formatted CSV. The text file is already tab delimited.

Batch File:

```
pushd %~dp0                    **Used to get current DIR
set path=%~dp0                 **Used to set a path variable to send to VBScript
txtToCsv.vbs %path%            **Used to invoke the VBScript
```

VBA Script:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 1 Then
     WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: txtToCsv Destination.csv"
     Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()
With oBook
    .Title = "Deal Data"
    .Subject = "Deal Data"
    .SaveAs WScript.Arguments(0)&"Deal_Data.xlsx"&YEAR(Date)&MONTH(Date)&DAY(Date)
End With

Dim sourceFile
Set sourceFile = "TEXT;"&WScript.Arguments(0)&"deal_data.txt"

Set ActiveSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sourceFile,    Destination:=ActiveCell)
    .Name = "deal_data"
        .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second script is VBScript, not VBA, even though you're calling Excel VBA methods in it. While those two languages share some similarities, there are also some fundamental differences.

1. You need a handle for accessing VBA methods and collections.
2. You cannot use name arguments in VBScript.

Also you already seem to have constructed the connection string in the variable `sourceFile`.

Change these 2 lines:

```
Set ActiveSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sourceFile,    Destination:=ActiveCell)
```

into this:

```
Set ActiveSheet = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(sourceFile, oExcel.ActiveCell)
```

and the problem should disappear.